# Different ways of getting complete url information in php

Tags: php

I come to know how to capture complete url using `$_SERVER` global variable like

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Using many stack overflow answers

I want to know is there any other way of capturing complete **URI** with out using the global variable `$_SERVER` and `request_uri`.

Comment: Any reason why not to use them?

Comment: Are you using Wordpress?

Comment: no reason particularly but i want to explore different paths of getting what i want

Comment: There's literally no reason why you shouldn't use this globals.

Comment: Why wasting time on this ? if it works ..

Comment: no i am not using wordpress and i am not using any framework

Comment: No reason not to use them, make a `print_r($_SERVER)`, you'll have your idea on how to get your URI according to your goals.

Comment: Depending on your environment, you could use something like `apache_getenv`, but it's backed onto the exact same information as the `$_SERVER` superglobal, so as has already been said, it doesn't serve any purpose. There are plenty of classes out there that will replicate this functionality and provide a cleaner interface, if you're just looking to avoid writing your own (this is a good thing).

Comment: @VincentDecaux  i was exploring the php src code where i find the files https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/SAPI.h#L2 and https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/url.h will gets the information about url's so i want to know is there is another way

Comment: Write [`<?php phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in a new file, open it in browser (using the web server, of course) and check the content of `$_SERVER[]` at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @axiac why not just `print_r($_SERVER);`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no (normal) way to do this. You either get information from `$_SERVER` or `$_GET`. You should use these and not other solutions, as they are designed for this. Using other options in normal situations should be avoided.

Exploring for alternative methods is good practice. In this case, this is the way to go. If you want to expand your skills, look for alternative *logic*, not an alternative variable.